# logrotate for already rotated logs

Tags: ubuntu, logrotate

We already have logs for an application that are separated for every day.
they look like this:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   23616 Jul  1  2018 01072018.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  340980 Aug  1 23:55 01082018.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   25793 Sep  1 23:55 01092018.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   94487 Oct  1 23:55 01102018.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   24658 Jul  2  2018 02072018.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  235299 Aug  2 23:55 02082018.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   41667 Sep  2 23:55 02092018.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   63921 Oct  2 23:55 02102018.log
```

how to keep last 1 month using logrotate?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate

Comment: @Doni - so whats the result?

Answer (score 0):

Set monthly in configuration file. For example:

```
/home/dirnov/www/letsee/logs/*.log {
    monthly
    missingok
    rotate 4
    compress
    notifempty
}
```

Moreover, do not add the flag -f when you run logrotate. The first time logrotate is run in a month it will rotate logs.

Comment: i am trying this now and will let you know the result